# Inserting into an mySQL database from a local html/javascript website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, cross-domain

**What I'm trying to do**

The intention of my program is to insert data from a **local** `HTML`/`JS` website into an **online** (non-local) `mySQL` database.

**What I've attempted so far**

The original method I was attempting to utilise to accomplish this was to, have my local website utilise javascript to post data via an online `PHP` file, then have this `PHP` file insert this information into a `mySQL` table. But I kept receiving *cross-origin request* related errors.

After reaching a wall programmatically, I opened up a [Stackoverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42590625/7631121) to determine whether it was even possible to post from a local website to an online `PHP` file, during which I was expertly informed this wasn't possible without modifying Chrome related policies on each machine attempting to visit this local website.

**Purpose of this thread**

To determine whether rather than posting via a `PHP` file to enable the inserting of data into a `mySQL` table from a **local** `HTML`/`JS` website, if there is another approach I've not considered.

**Reasoning for not modifying browser policies:**

I don't have control over which policies are implemented on user browsers or which browser they choose to utilise. Similarly I'm not able to install additional software onto their systems e.g. Apache etc.

**Overall Problem**

As the methods I've attempted so far to post from a **local** `HTML`/`JS` website as a means to insert into a `mySQL` database have so far been unsuccessful. I've posted here to determine whether there was another approach that I have not yet considered rather than posting data via `PHP` files, which could be applied to my source code, rather than a user's web-browser to allow for the execution of `mySQL` queries initiated from a local `HTML`/`JS` website?

**JS Code:**

```
function uploadPetData(petName, petAge, petType) {

    var urlString ="Pet_Name="+petName+"&Pet_Age="+petAge+"&Pet_Type="+petType;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.com/test.php',
        crossDomain: true,
        data : urlString,   
        contentType:contentType,   
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var value = responseData.someKey;
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("...","...","...","...");

$petName = $_POST['Pet_Name'];
$petAge = $_POST['Pet_Age'];
$petType = $_POST['Pet_Type'];

$petName = mysqli_escape_string($con, $petName);
$petAge = mysqli_escape_string($con, $petAge);
$petType = mysqli_escape_string($con, $petType);

$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Pets (Name, Season, Episode)
                             VALUES ('$petName', '$petAge', '$petType')");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Is requirement to only post data? Or is a response expected by user?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm hoping to carry out two requests from the **local** `HTML`/`JS` website to the **online** `mySQL` db table. The first would simply insert a row into the **online** `mySQL` db table mentioned above. The second would determine whether a particular row existed within the **online** `mySQL` db table and if determined as present, a `TRUE`  or `FALSE` value would be returned.

Comment: If user needs to be online to post and get data, why do you not create an `html` `document` online for user to submit `<form>`, and get response from server?

Comment: If I understand you right, you're asking if I want the user to be capable of inserting data into the online `mySQL` db table, why not simply put the whole website online. The reason I don't want to put full website online is, I want the website itself to be completely private to a number of selected users. But information can be shared between these local `HTML`/`JS` web-pages via the use of data provided by and uploaded to the **online** `mySQL` db table. If I've misunderstood what you mean please correct me, as I'm really hoping for an applicable solution to the above mentioned problem.

Comment: Not put website online. Provide a means for user to exchange data with server online.

Comment: @guest271314 Do you mean place a form **online** as a means to automatically relay the information from the **local** `HTML`/`JS` website to the **online** `mySQL` db? (as a replacement for my original attempt at a `PHP` relay) Or do you mean there should be a form element placed **online** which the user should physically visit and enter their information manually? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 If you're referring to the use of a manual form, that's not really applicable for my project. But if you're referring to some variation of automatic relay as I originally attempted with PHP, could you please provide an example? as i've not done something like this before.

Comment: Yes, an online `form`. User needs to be online to transfer data. Why would there not be a `form` to get data if user is already online?

Comment: @guest271314 As discussed in **detail** above,  the `HTML`/`JS` website is being stored locally. It is just the `MySQL` db being stored online. The intention for this project is, the user would make decisions on the local private `HTML`/`JS` website, then these decisions would he reflected within the online `mySQL` db. Such a data-transfer  would occur in an automated manner. Hence my original attempt to relay this information from `JS` to `PHP` to `MySQL`. As such, for both automation and privacy reasons, placing a form online for users to manually enter data into would be inapplicable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use server-side js as standalone client on each machine if you plan to deal with db directly. Browser js wasn't designed for this kind of interactions.

If you decide to keep using browser js you'll need a rest api to accomplish your objectives. You'll also need to mount your files into a local webserver (nginx or apache) in order to deal with cross-site problems of your client-side js. After that you can simply interact with your endpoints with plain ajax or promises or something more advanced like RxJs Observables.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **Overall Problem**
>
> As the methods I've attempted so far to post from a **local**
>   `HTML`/`JS` website as a means to insert into a `mySQL` database have
>   so far been unsuccessful. I've posted here to determine whether there
>   was another approach that I have not yet considered rather than
>   posting data via `PHP` files, which could be applied to my source
>   code, rather than a user's web-browser to allow for the execution of
>   `mySQL` queries initiated from a local `HTML`/`JS` website?

The requirement is not possible at a browser with default settings; or without user action allowing the application access to their OS local filesystem, and make cross domain requests.

What you are trying to achieve requires some form of user action

- User lauches browser with specific flags or preferences set at browser to allow cross origin request from `file:` protocol;
- User installs a browser extension or app, with appropriate permissions set to perform cross origin requests; for example [`chrome.fileSystemProvider`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystemProvider); [`chrome.syncFileSystem`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem); [PowerShell - FileSystem Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider); see also [Method for streaming data from browser to server via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899536/method-for-streaming-data-from-browser-to-server-via-http/37903033?s=2|1.1710#37903033), [jQuery File Upload Plugin: Is possible to preserve the structure of uploaded folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106121/jquery-file-upload-plugin-is-possible-to-preserve-the-structure-of-uploaded-fol/37107246#37107246);
- User utilizes a web server at browser [Opera Unite](http://help.opera.com/Linux/10.50/en/unite.html); [POW -- Plain Old Webserver](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pow-plain-old-webserver/); 
  [Embedding an HTTP Web Server in Firefox OS](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/02/embedding-an-http-web-server-in-firefox-os/); [Use Firefox OS as web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062801/use-firefox-os-as-web-server);  [Building web server using chrome.socket API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088586/building-web-server-using-chrome-socket-api); [Is it possible to embed a HTTP server in a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053244/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-http-server-in-a-google-chrome-extension);
- User installs a shell script, sets appropriate permissions to allow shell script to read local file and use OS networking tools to communicate with server.

Alternatives

- Adjust requirement, create a `<form>` or `<input type="file">` element at an online `html` `document`, where user can perform user action to upload file;
- Use "[cloud storage](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/onedrive-dropbox-google-drive-and-box-which-cloud-storage-service-is-right-for-you/)";
- Provide user with adequate instructions as to how to make a `POST` request at command-line, for example, using [`cURL`](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request);
- As described at Answers at linked Question, provide guidance for user to launch chromium with `--diable-web-security`, and possibly `--allow-file-access-from-files` flags set; [Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari and Chrome](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests); [Disable cross domain web security in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711924/disable-cross-domain-web-security-in-firefox).

The issue is once an external application has read-write-execute permissions at user local filesystem, the script could be a potential security risk.

If user is in agreement with the potential security risk of allowing your application to read, write and execute arbitrary scripts at their local filesystem, they should be in agreement with either a cloud storage solution, for example, a service that you compose; using and online `<form>` to upload files; or omitting browser from procedure altogether and performing the request to `POST` files at command-line of the given operating system.

> As discussed in **detail** above, the `HTML`/`JS` website is being
>   stored locally. It is just the `MySQL` db being stored online. The
>   intention for this project is, the user would make decisions on the
>   local private `HTML`/`JS` website, then these decisions would he
>   reflected within the online `mySQL` db. Such a data-transfer would
>   occur in an automated manner. Hence my original attempt to relay this
>   information from `JS` to `PHP` to `MySQL`. As such, for both
>   automation and privacy reasons, placing a form online for users to
>   manually enter data into would be inapplicable.

The command-line option being the most suitable to being "automated", for example, using `cron`

- [How do I setup a cron job on OS X to run a curl command at a specific time every day?](https://superuser.com/questions/1144910/how-do-i-setup-a-cron-job-on-os-x-to-run-a-curl-command-at-a-specific-time-every)
- [How do you run a crontab in Cygwin on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707184/how-do-you-run-a-crontab-in-cygwin-on-windows)
- [Using curl to automate HTTP jobs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)

It is interesting to note that you have not mentioned authenticating the users whose filesystem your application would have access to, and whose local files are being stored in a remote `MySQL` database

- [How to upload (FTP) files to server in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894347/how-to-upload-ftp-files-to-server-in-a-bash-script)
- [Setting up a cron for transferring a file through FTP at 5 PM daily](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/aix-43/setting-up-a-cron-for-transferring-a-file-through-ftp-at-5-pm-daily-934622/)
- [Copying a file to a remote ftp server with bash](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663776)